# ASP.NET core EF ambiguous constructor

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net5

I use ASP.NET Core with .NET 5 and recently wanted to change from local development to Azure Web production mode.

Locally I use SQLite and everything works fine, on production I want to use Azure SQL.
However when I want to migrate my database, I get a rather long exception:

```
System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Server.Calendars.CalendarDataContext' for the parameter 'calendarDataContext' of method 'Configure' on type 'Server.Startup'.
 ---&gt; System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to activate type 'Server.Calendars.CalendarDataContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Server.Calendars.CalendarDataContext])
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7_0.&lt;GetCallSite&gt;b__0(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4_0.&lt;Build&gt;b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass15_0.&lt;UseStartup&gt;b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutoRegisterMiddleware.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4_0.&lt;Configure&gt;b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass0_0.&lt;Configure&gt;g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass2_0.&lt;Configure&gt;b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass0_0.&lt;Configure&gt;b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

My class `CalendarDataContext .cs` for Azure SQL

```
public class CalendarDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CalendarEntry> CalendarEntries { get; set; }


    protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public CalendarDataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public CalendarDataContext(DbContextOptions<CalendarDataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        if (!options.IsConfigured)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CalendarDatabase"));
        }
    }
}
```

and `CalendarDataContextSqlite.cs` for SQLite

```
public class CalendarDataContextSqlite : CalendarDataContext
{
    public CalendarDataContextSqlite(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration) { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        if (!options.IsConfigured)
        {
            var databaseName = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CalendarDatabase");
            var databasePath = PathHelper.DataPath(databaseName);
            options.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + databasePath);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the issue is with the line `CalendarDataContext(DbContextOptions<CalendarDataContext> options)` that I need for creating a temporary InMemory-Database for my tests.

How can I make this ambiguous constructor less ambiguous?

**Edit:** Add `startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Environment = environment;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (Environment.IsProduction())
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CalendarDataContext>();
        }
        else if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CalendarDataContext, CalendarDataContextSqlite>();
        }
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
        IWebHostEnvironment env,
        CalendarDataContext calendarDataContext)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        calendarDataContext.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your app you are trying to inject CalendarDataContext as a constructor parameter.  Maybe into a CalendarService or similar?  The problem is that when the DI container is trying to provide that CalendarDataContext, it cannot decide which constructor to use.  You CalendarDataContext should be configured in your StartUp so there should not be any need to provide the 2nd constructor for (IConfiguration) in case the options are not configured.  Then, there'd only be one constructor and life will be good.

Comment: Just noticed the problem is in Configure method of StartUp.  Post your Startup.cs file as well.

Comment: I added my startup.cs to the question

Comment: Just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Add IConfiguration as a local member in your Startup.cs

```
IConfiguration Configuration;
public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    Environment = environment;
}
```

then Register a *configured* CalendarDataContext or CalendarDataContextSqlite in Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (Environment.IsProduction())
    {
        services.AddDbContext<CalendarDataContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("CalendarDatabase"));
    }
    else if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddDbContext<CalendarDataContext, CalendarDataContextSqlite>(options => {
            var databaseName = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CalendarDatabase");
            var databasePath = PathHelper.DataPath(databaseName);
            options.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + databasePath);
        });
    }
}
```

Then, CalendarDataContext:

```
public class CalendarDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CalendarEntry> CalendarEntries { get; set; }


    public CalendarDataContext(DbContextOptions<CalendarDataContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    protected CalendarDataContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) { }
}
```

And, CalendarDataContextSqlite:

```
public class CalendarDataContextSqlite : CalendarDataContext
{
    public CalendarDataContextSqlite(DbContextOptions<CalendarDataContextSqlite> options)
        : base(options) { }
}
```

Now,

No need for the OnConfiguring in the context classes.

In production you'll have a configured CalendarDataContext to be injected wherever the constructor asks for a CalendarDataContext.

And for developerment you'll have a configured CalendarDataContextSqlite to be injected wherever the constructor asks for a CalendarDataContext.

That configured context will also be injected into Startup.Configure so you can migrate your database.

Comment: This looks promising, but I get an error when compiling in `CalendarDataContextSqlite` saying `cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<CalendarDataContextSqlite>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<CalendarDataContext>'`
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: If I keep `IConfiguration configuration` in both classes `CalendarDataContextSqlite` and `CalendarDataContext`, I get an error in `Startup.Configure` while database migration.

Comment: For the first issue, try removing the GenericType from the Constructor definition, i.e. just use CalendarDataContext(DbContextOptions options)  &  CalendarDataContextSqlite(DbContextOptions options).

Comment: For the second issue, I don't see any need to retain a reference to IConfiguration in your context classes.

Comment: I found the issue as well with the specified `DbContextOptions<CalendarDataContext>` and edited your answer accorindgly. Thank you very much!! Everything works now as expected, also the migration.